# web3.eth.getAccounts() : Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: web3js, remix, contract-deployment, rinkeby

```
 const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
 const Web3 = require('web3');
 const provider = new HDWalletProvider( 'passphrase', 'rinkeby.infura.io/v3/mytoken' );
 const web3 = new Web3(provider);
 const deploy = async () =>{ const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts(); } deploy();
```

gives

> TypeError:Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at
>   GetAccountsMethod.afterExecution

versions used:

```
 "solc": "^0.4.24",
 "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.4",
 "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.46"
```

any solution woud be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're gonna have to do a little more than that (share more code, and share more efforts made investigating this problem) if you're hoping to get help here.

Comment: const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
  'tomato rate sheriff course end labor topic above curious this rail group',
  'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/ff9cefedf8924477a6d236e5e36fc06b'
);
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const deploy = async () =>{
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
}
deploy();

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to post those 12 words?

Comment: raised : https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2405

Comment: downgrade it to 1.0.0-beta.36, it will work.

Comment: Thanks Aniket it worked but web3.eth.getAccounts() method doesn't give any output.

Comment: did u find any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You might need to remove the truffle build in your directory

```
rm -R build/
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same error and in my case I accidentally imported the *dbg.json* file instead of json file.